# How do I run the phpunit in a single file for all the model/controller

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I am having a challenge with the phpunit, the test runs perfectly for the user inputs but doesn't recognise the product function. I have tried to delete the user authentication functions to run the product insertion, etc but it seems not working.

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature\Auth;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Tests\TestCase;
use \App\Models\Product;
use \App\Models\User;
class LoginTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic feature test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    
    
    public function test_user_can_view_a_login_form(){
        $response = $this->get('user/signin');
        $response->assertStatus(200);
        $response->assertViewIs('user.signin');
    }
    public function test_user_cannot_view_a_login_from_when_authenticated() {

       $user = new User([
           'email' => 'jobtest@test.com',
           'password' => bcrypt($password = 'i-want-this-job'),
       ]);
       if ($user === null) {
           $user->save();
       }
       else{
           echo "User exists";
       }
       
       $response = $this->post('user/signin', [
           'email' => $user->email,
           'password' => $password,
       ]);
      
        $response = $this->actingAs($user)->get('user/signin');
        $this->assertAuthenticatedAs($user);
      
    }

**THE PRODUCT METHODS START FROM HERE** 
    public function user_can_access_home_page() {
        $response = $this->get('/');
        $response->assertStatus(200);
        $response->assertViewIs('/');
     }
   public function can_user_insert_product() {
        $product = new Product([
        'imagePath' => 'https://i0.wp.com/ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HLB1V4vwbjLuK1Rjy0Fhq6xpdFXaJ/Elegant-Women-Dresses-Bodycon-Office-Formal-Business-Work-Party-Sheath-Tunic-Pencil-Midi-O-neck-Short.jpg?fit=800%2C800&ssl=1',
        'title' => 'Elegant Women Dresses',
        'description' => 'Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the content',
        'price' => '8',
        'quantity' => '3'
    ]);  
    $product->save();
    if($product) {
        echo "Product inserted";
    }
  

    $response = $this->post('/', [
        'imagePath' => $product->imagePath,
        'title' => $product->title,
        'description' => $product->description,
        'price' => $product->price,
        'quantity' => $product->quantity,
    ]);
    $response = assertRedirect('/');
}


}
```

I have also tried to create another test file for it, but still showing **No tests found in class "Tests\Feature\Auth\LoginTest".**[image]

Whereas when appended in the same test file, it will run and ignore the product methods.
Or do I need to run **php artisan make:test Auth/LoginTest** for user login separately and run php artisan make:test Product/ProductTest because I don't know why the user will work and the product will not [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `phpunit` tests to run they either start with the word `test` or have a `@test` annotation. Your product tests does not follow these rules.

The usually solution

```
public function test_can_user_insert_product(){
```

Or the annotation solution

```
/** @test **/
public function can_user_insert_product
```

Comment: Thanks... I do appreciate this. I didn't take note of that.